# Chamada HTTP erro ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG

Tags: jquery, html, laravel-5, http, memory-limit

Estou submitando um formulário com muitas informações e recebo a seguinte mensagem:

```
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG
```

Pequeno trecho do código:

```
$("#editForm").submit();
```

Entendo que o erro é por estar enviando muitos dados, mas tem alguma maneira de aumentar esse limite?